# Octave: Error in installing octave control package

Tags: package, octave, gnu

Actually my initial goal was to install "signal" package but for this package, there is a dependency of control package. So, I am going to install it and I am bumped to the following problem.

```
kg install "https://github.com/gnu-octave/pkg-control/releases/download/control-3.5.1/control-3.5.1.tar.gz"
In file included from __control_helper_functions__.cc:7:
lti_input_idx.cc: In function ‘octave_value_list F__lti_input_idx__(const octave_value_list&, int)’:
lti_input_idx.cc:96:13: error: ‘range’ is not a member of ‘octave’
   96 |     octave::range<double> mat_idx (1, idx-offset);
      |             ^~~~~
lti_input_idx.cc:96:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
   96 |     octave::range<double> mat_idx (1, idx-offset);
      |                   ^~~~~~
lti_input_idx.cc:97:13: error: ‘range’ is not a member of ‘octave’
   97 |     octave::range<double> opt_idx (idx+1-offset, len);
      |             ^~~~~
lti_input_idx.cc:97:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
   97 |     octave::range<double> opt_idx (idx+1-offset, len);
      |                   ^~~~~~
lti_input_idx.cc:100:17: error: ‘opt_idx’ was not declared in this scope
  100 |     retval(1) = opt_idx;
      |                 ^~~~~~~
lti_input_idx.cc:101:17: error: ‘mat_idx’ was not declared in this scope
  101 |     retval(0) = mat_idx;
      |                 ^~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:69: __control_helper_functions__.oct] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: Entering directory '/tmp/oct-Y9iHDK/control-3.5.1/src'
tar -xzf slicot.tar.gz
/usr/bin/mkoctfile -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations  __control_helper_functions__.cc
mkdir sltmp
mv slicot/src/*.f ./sltmp
mv slicot/src_aux/*.f ./sltmp
if [ "1" = "1" ]; then \
        echo "copy routines using DGGES"; \
        cp SB04OD.fortran ./sltmp/SB04OD.f; \
        cp SG03AD.fortran ./sltmp/SG03AD.f; \
        cp SG03BD.fortran ./sltmp/SG03BD.f; \
fi;
copy routines using DGGES
cp AB08NX.fortran ./sltmp/AB08NX.f
cp AG08BY.fortran ./sltmp/AG08BY.f
cp SB01BY.fortran ./sltmp/SB01BY.f
cp SB01FY.fortran ./sltmp/SB01FY.f
cp SB06ND.fortran ./sltmp/SB06ND.f
cp TB01MD.fortran ./sltmp/TB01MD.f
cp TB01ND.fortran ./sltmp/TB01ND.f
cp TB01ZD.fortran ./sltmp/TB01ZD.f
cp TG04BX.fortran ./sltmp/TG04BX.f
cp ODLTZM.fortran ./sltmp/ODLTZM.f
cp makefile.slicot ./sltmp/makefile
cd sltmp; /usr/bin/mkoctfile -w -c MA02ID.f; rm MA02ID.f; /usr/bin/mkoctfile -c *.f;
ar -rc slicotlibrary.a ./sltmp/*.o
rm -rf sltmp slicot
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/oct-Y9iHDK/control-3.5.1/src'

error: pkg: error running 'make' for the control package.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 110 column 9
    install at line 198 column 7
    pkg at line 568 column 9
>> pkg install "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/octave/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/signal-1.4.3.tar.gz"
error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
   signal needs control >= 2.4
```

I wonder if anyone has even faced this or similar problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

I tried googling the error but could not find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of the package with a fix of this issue will be released soon. As a workaround, you can download [version 3.5.0](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/octave/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/control-3.5.0.tar.gz), save it locally, and install it in octave with the command `pkg install control-3.5.0.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem in debian bullseye. There you can install the octave packages via the debian repository and your native cli:

```
apt-get install octave-control
```

Then you will get version 3.2.0-5

https://packages.debian.org/source/stable/octave-control